# Redactor pagebreak plugin and linking to pages

Tags: redactor, pagination

I am trying to split entry into multiple pages.

In accordance with the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields), I am using this code on single-entry template:

```
{{ entry.body.getPage(1) }}

{% if entry.body.getTotalPages() > 1 %}
  <a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading…</a>
{% endif %}
```

However `{{ entry.url }}` is always pointing to the same page that I'm on (base entry URL) without any pagination number, so I never get to second page.
I have checked that `{{entry.body.getTotalPages()}}` returns 2, so the pagebreak plugin is working.

What am I missing here?

**Answer:**

Here's the working code that I got with Brad Bell's help:

```
{% set currentPage = 1 %}
{% if craft.request.getParam('page') is not empty %}
    {% set currentPage = craft.request.getParam('page') %}
{% endif %}

{{ entry.body.getPage(currentPage) }}

{% if entry.body.getTotalPages() > 1 %}
    {% set totalPages = entry.body.getTotalPages() %}

    {% for i in 1..totalPages %}
    <a href="{{ url(entry.url, {page: i}) }}">go to page: {{ i }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is the docs you're referring to will simple output the first "page" of the Rich Text field and if there are more pages show a "Continue Reading" link that loads the full entry.

For the functionality you're looking for you'd have to do something like this (completely untested):

```
{% set totalPages = entry.body.getTotalPages() %}

{% for i in 1..totalPages %}
    <a href="{{ url(entry.url, {page: i}) }}">{{ i }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then your template would grab the `page` from the querystring and display it  using `entry.body.getPage(page)`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it working. Clearly the docs are missing this part.